# Android fragment on select arguments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, arguments

I am trying to pass arguments to a fragment and then execute a function based on the arguments posted, in java/android using the examples from Google:

At first, I thought that the issue was that I am not executing onResume when the fragment is set visible, however I have also noticed that the numbers appear out of order.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager mViewPager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }


    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        {

            public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
                {
                    super(fm);
                }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position)
                {
                    Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();

                    args.putInt("position", position + 1);
                    fragment.setArguments(args);

                    return fragment;
                }

            @Override
            public int getCount()
                {
                    return 3;
                }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
                {
                    Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
                    switch (position)
                        {
                        case 0:
                            return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                        case 1:
                            return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
                        case 2:
                            return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase(l);
                        }
                    return null;
                }
        }

    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment
        {
            private int position = -1;

            public DummySectionFragment()
                {
                }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy, container, false);

                    position = getArguments().getInt("position");

                    return rootView;
                }

            @Override
            public void onResume()
                {
                    super.onResume();

                    Log.d("App", "Position: " + position);
                }
        }
}
```

Logcat:

```
03-05 09:44:53.653: D/App(23062): Position: 1
03-05 09:44:53.653: D/App(23062): Position: 2
03-05 09:45:02.473: D/App(23062): Position: 3
03-05 09:45:12.008: D/App(23062): Position: 1
03-05 09:45:13.353: D/App(23062): Position: 3
03-05 09:45:15.568: D/App(23062): Position: 1
```

I have looked at other posts but most of the resolutions appear to be to use multiple fragments i.e.

```
f = new Fragment1();
f = new FragmentOther();
f = new FragmentBobbityHead();
```

However this is not an option for me.

Comment: you are not explaining what you did to get the Logcat-Output. There is no problem to have all Fragments the same class. It seems the problem is related to creating a new object each time in `getItem`, but this can be only a guess

Comment: I am not sure that I am explaining it very well, if you look at the order of the Logcat positions it is not displaying all of the numbers in order when I swipe left and right on the screen. I only posted a segment of the logcat showing the "Position" as the full logcat is too large to post. How can I display the page position each time the fragment is selected? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the `getItem()` method because it makes no guarantees when it is called. It may be called when the `Fragment` isn't even visible to the user yet. Depending on your exact use case, you may be able to use a `TabListener`. This will notify you when a particular `Fragment` is shown to the user, one at a time.

```
ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            mSectionsPagerAdapter.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        }
    };
```

[RefiCalcActivity.java](https://github.com/jimblesm/reficalcpro/blob/master/src/com/swick/reficalcpro/RefiCalcActivity.java) from a project of mine shows an example you can use. I ran into this exact same problem.

If you want to learn more about fragments, check out this blog post on `Fragments` and `Activities`: http://www.zerotohired.com/2015/02/passing-data-between-activities-and-fragments-in-android/